# How to replace elastic beanstalk instance with new EB environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I've currently created a new AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment and I want to figure out how to replace the old EB environment currently setup.

I can't seem to find any reference in Route 53 to the instance which points to the xxx-oldinstance.elasticbeanstalk.com. I even checked to see if it using the IPv4 DNS as mentioned on some docs but nothing is relating to the older instance.

What do I do in order to replace my older instance with this new instance I have created?

Comment: EB allows you to [swap CNAMEs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html) between environments.

Comment: That's perfect! Am going to try that out thank you!

Comment: No problem. If it will work for you, I can make an answer with some extra details and link, if you don't mind?

Comment: Yeah for sure I can remove my answer if you'd like :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

EB provides convenient option of **swapping CNAMEs** between its environments as described in:

- [Blue/Green deployments with Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html)

Thanks to this:

> you deploy the new version to a **separate environment**, and then swap CNAMEs of the two environments to **redirect traffic** to the new version instantly.